# VBA String to Integer without rounding

Tags: string, vba, integer, decimal

I want to convert a `String` into `Integer` and keep the decimal places.
I tried multiple things like `Foramat` and `CInt` but all of them end up rounding my value.

My Code is:

```
Dim posZ As Integer
Dim TestZ As Integer
Dim strTestZ As String
Dim TestZold As Integer

For i = 1 To tllength
  posZ = InStr(tlmold(i), "Z=")
  strTestZ = Mid(tlmold(i), posZ + 2, 5)

  TestZ = Format(strTestZ, "0.0000")

   If TestZold = TestZ Or (TestZold - TestZ) > 0.02 Or (TestZ - TestZold) > 0.02 Then
   countLip = countLip + 1
   End If
 TestZold = TestZ
Next I
```

e.g. the first value of `strTestZ` in the array `tlmold()` would be **0.085**, 2nd would be **0.097**.
And I want to compare them..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer is a whole number variable. Use double instead.

Answer (score 2):

"*I want to convert a String into Integer and keep the decimal places.*" - not possible, Integer is "Ganz Zahl".

However, I think that this is not your problem. I notice that you are from Germany, thus you are obviously experiencing a problem with the comma separator, which is a comma in Germany. In USA and the VBEditor it is a dot. Thus, you have to convert a bit your input to what is expected. `Replace()` is the way to do it.

See for yourself:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputA          As String
    Dim convertedNumber As Double

    inputA = "0.085"
    convertedNumber = CDbl(inputA)
    Debug.Print convertedNumber

    inputA = Replace(inputA, ".", ",")
    convertedNumber = CDbl(inputA)
    Debug.Print convertedNumber

End Sub
```

The first time you print you would get `85` and the second time, you would get `0,085`, as expected.

Comment: The inputs are with "dot".  System is set up on english but thanks for the idea!

Comment: I get "0.085" and "85"

Comment: @rosi97 - if you ask an American person what do you think he/she would get?

Comment: @rosi97 - Your system is not on English setup, if you are getting two different values from the code aboive. The VBEditor is on English setup, but your Windows uses comma with a decimal separator. This may be a problem, if you are reading from external file or if you are writing VBA formulas in Excel.

Comment: Okay, then I don't know where this is coming from. Keyboard Input language is "English (United States)". Anyways the code works fine for me now. Thanks for the info.